# Buffered reader VS listenUDP

Tags: go, udp, buffer, bufferedreader

If I am "infinitely" using the `buffered reader`  to wait for messages from the server, is this not pretty much the same as using `ListenUDP`?

But if use `ListenUDP`, then I've created another server ...

Is it bad practice to "infinitely" collect from this `buffered reader` or is that in general how it is done with the client?

**client.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "net"
    "sync"
    "bufio"
)

func xyz(conn net.Conn, p []byte) {
    rd := bufio.NewReader(conn)
    for {
        fmt.Printf("line\n")
        _, err := rd.Read(p)
        if err == nil {
            fmt.Printf("SERVER : %s\n", p)
        } else {
            fmt.Printf("Some error %v\n", err)
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    var wg = &sync.WaitGroup{}
    p :=  make([]byte, 2048)
    conn, err := net.Dial("udp", "127.0.0.1:1234")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v", err)
        return
    }
    wg.Add(1)
    go xyz(conn, p)
    time.Sleep(2 * time.Second);
    fmt.Fprintf(conn, "Give me a hash to work on ...")
    time.Sleep(4 * time.Second)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

**server.go**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net"
)

func sendResponse(conn *net.UDPConn, addr *net.UDPAddr, hash string) {
    _,err := conn.WriteToUDP([]byte("Hello, here is the hash  - " + hash), addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Couldn't send response %v", err)
    }
}

func main() {
    hash := "36";
    p := make([]byte, 2048)
    addr := net.UDPAddr{
        Port: 1234,
        IP: net.ParseIP("127.0.0.1"),
    }
    ser, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", &addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
    for {
        _, remoteaddr, err := ser.ReadFromUDP(p)
        fmt.Printf("CLIENT : %v : %s\n", remoteaddr, p)
        if err !=  nil {
            fmt.Printf("Some error  %v", err)
            continue
        }
        go sendResponse(ser, remoteaddr, hash)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use gofmt!

Comment: Using bufio with a UDP connection doesn't usually make any sense. UDP is based on individual datagrams, what is the goal of trying to use the buffered reader?

Comment: @JimB ... using the buffered reader to keep waiting for message from server. At any point, the server could send a message through the connection. Then the client, will do things based on that message and send message back to the server.

Comment: The bufio.Reader doesn't read in the background, it reads when you call Read, so even if it's working it's adding another layer of buffering for no reason. It also has no notion of individual datagram, so your `rd.Read` calls could return parts of multiple datagrams, and though it's unlikely, there's no guarantee that the bufio.Reader is going to call Read with enough buffer space to receive the entire datagram and will lose data.

Comment: @JimB ... another layer of buffering? What is the first layer here? How would   you suggest I grab messages from the UDP server?

Comment: @MattClendenen: `rd.Read` is copying the data into the `bufio.Reader` buffer, then copying it again into `p`. You could just as well skip that and read directly into `p`. Using bufio can't help here, because UDP isn't stream based, so there's going to be the same number of syscalls no matter what. The extra buffer is the lesser problem though because if your buffer becomes full you're going to lose data on partial reads, and you still can't differentiate the datagrams that are already in the buffer.

Comment: @MattClendenen: BTW, I still don't understand the question at all. `net.ListenUDP` opens a udp socket, and `bufio.Reader` is a buffered `io.Reader` which are completely different things -- I don't know what the comparison is supposed to be.

Comment: @JimB ... My misunderstanding was that I needed `bufio.NewReader` in order to read a message back from the server through `conn` .. but apparently I can read directly from the `conn` into `p`? The end goal here is to constantly listen for a message back from the server through `conn`. I am hoping for a functionality that is similar to an `event` in jQuery. Something like `$(conn).onGetMessage(function(e) { do stuff });` So, wait for the message and when there is a message, do something.

Comment: @MattClendenen: a `net.Conn` is an `io.Reader`, which is why you were able to use it as an argument to `bufio.NewReader`. You wait for a message by calling `Read`, and you "do stuff" when `Read` returns.

Comment: @JimB ... ok! If you are interested in putting that as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a `bufio.Reader` to read from a `net.Conn`, and in the case of a UDP connection, it can only cause problems.

UDP is not stream based, so you will always need to read each individual datagram. In the best case a `bufio.Reader` is just buffering the data one extra time, in the worst case the buffer is near full and you only get a partial read, losing data. You also can no longer differentiate the messages once multiple datagrams have been buffered unless they contain additional framing.

Just read directly from the `net.Conn` into your `[]byte`:

```
for {
    n, err := conn.Read(p)
    fmt.Printf("SERVER : %s\n", p[:n])
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Some error %v\n", err)
        return
    }
}
```